# Is it safer to send a signed apk or an unsigned apk to someone over email?

Tags: android

I am developing an android app and I need to send the apk to someone. My question is simple. What should I do in order to prevent him/her from misusing it. Can someone simply upload an apk to play store from his account if I send him a signed apk. If I however send him/her a debug apk he might be able to decompile it. What is the best approach in this case. I am using proguard in my app and so a signed apk would be safe. But I am not sure if he can simply upload it to playstore. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Simple. The other person, cannot upload to playstore as that person is not a developer and would not have the necessary keys used to sign the apk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### If you have a developer account

Safest option is to distribute it using `alpha/beta testing channels on google play`. Add the recipient's email to the tester list and he will be able to download it. It also gives you the flexibility to add others in an easy fashion and not having to upload/send the apk every time.

#### Update (In cases where you do not have a developer account already)

signed apk can be directly uploaded to the play store if the package name or application id is unique. i would suggest you `temporarily change the application id to some existing app's application id like gmail/whatsapp/(any other published app) and then send it with proguard enabled`. That way he will not be able to upload it (as is) since the application id or package name will not be unique.

*Suggestion: Pick a non popular published app to use the application id temporarily (not gmail/whatsapp/facebook) because there are high changes these apps are already installed on the receiver's phone and he will have trouble installing your apk.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This seems the best option, might sound funny but I have not yet got a developer account, would be getting one in a couple of days. In the meantime I needed to send it to few people. In that case, a signed apk with proguard enabled would be safe enough right ?

Comment: Thanks for the update, nice trick. This solves my problem. I have just one doubt though hope you can clear it. @t0mm13b has written that the person can't upload the apk since he doesn't have the necessary keys. Though I am sure that he/she can't publish an update without the keys but can he/she or can he/she not publish it if he/she has the signed apk which has a unique id? Although you have clearly mentioned in your answer that he can. I just needed to confirm that !!

Comment: he can sign the unsigned apk with his own keys and upload it.

Comment: Thanks for the response !!